# Visual Studio .vstemplate files not copying files using $projectname$ parameter

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I am having trouble getting Visual Studio project templates to work correctly.
I have edited the `.vstemplate` file in order to allow VS to rename project files when a new project is created from the template.
Some of the files are not copied or renamed when the new project is created.

I have a C++ project named Minimal that I have exported as a template.
I am currently NOT using any replaceable parameters in the Minimal template project.

The `Minimal.zip` folder in the Project Templates directory contains:
`__TemplateIcon.ico` (created by VS when the project was exported)
`Minimal.cpp` (my code)
`Minmal.rc` (a resource file containing a string table with one entry)
`Minimal.vcxproj` (created by VS at project creation time),
`Minimal.vcxproj.filters` (created by VS at project creation time)
`MyTemplate.vstemplate` (an XML file created by VS when the project was exported)
`resource.h` (created by VS at project creation time).

The `MyTemplate.vstemplate` file looks like this after editing:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Minimal</Name>
    <Description>&lt;No description available&gt;</Description>
    <ProjectType>VC</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>Minimal</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="Minimal.vcxproj" File="Minimal.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">Minimal.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.cpp">Minimal.cpp</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="resource.h">resource.h</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$projectname$.rc">Minimal.rc</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I edited the ProjectItem entries to use the `$projectname$` parameters.
Two ProjectItems have ReplaceParameters set to "false" and a TargetFileName set to `$projectname$`.
One ProjectItem has ReplaceParameters set to "false" and TargetFileName unedited.
One ProjectItem has ReplaceParameters set to "true" and TargetFileName set to `$projectname$`.

I have a project named Test that I created from the Minimal template.
I would expect the Test project folder to contain one file for each ProjectItem, and the files that use the `$projectname$` parameter to be renamed as `Test.something`.

The Test project folder actually contains this:
`Test.sln` (created by VS)
`resource.h` (not renamed, as expected)
`Test.vcxproj` (renamed, as expected)
`Test.vcxproj.filters` (renamed, as expected)
`Test.vcxoproj.user` (created by VS).

The Test project folder does not contain any `.cpp` or `.rc` file.
I have also tried not using `$projectname$` for the `.cpp` file and the `.rc` file, and just used their original names, and they get copied into the new project.

Does anyone know what I need to do to make it work correctly with renamed files?

Comment: According to this website, [link]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/template-parameters?view=vs-2019all parameter names are lower case.